# Check whether a parsed Protocol Buffers (Protobuf) proto3 message is valid

Tags: c++, validation, parsing, serialization, protocol-buffers

I currently need to transfer a Protobuf message of a given type `Foo` over the network and handle it on reception.

I am using Protobuf 3.5.1 and the `proto3` language.

On reception I do the following:

1. Create an empty instance of the expected type `Foo` (via a *Factory Method*, since it may change).
2. Parse the message from a `CodedInputStream` (constructed from the data received from the network).
3. Validate whether the parsing has been successful.

Here is a minimal code snippet illustrating the concrete problem:

```
// Create the empty Protobuf message of the EXPECTED type.
std::shared_ptr<google::protobuf::Message> message = std::make_unique<Foo>();

// Create the CodedInputStream from the network data.
google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream stream{receive_buffer_.data(), static_cast<int>(bytes_transferred)};

if (message->ParseFromCodedStream(&stream) && stream.ConsumedEntireMessage() && message->IsInitialized()) {
  // Message is of correct type and correctly parsed.
} else {
  // Message is NOT VALID.
  // TODO: This does not work if sending a message of type `Bar`.
}
```

Everything works flawless if the sender transfers messages of the expected type `Foo`, but things get weird if sending a message of another type `Bar`.

Both messages have a similar structure (they only difference is the `oneof` type which uses different types (but may use identical field identity values):

```
message Foo {

  First first = 1;

  oneof second {

    A a = 2;
    B b = 3;
  }
}

message Bar {

  First first = 1;

  oneof second {

    C c = 2;
    D d = 3;
  }
}
```

I haven't found a way yet, that detects whether the received Protobuf message type is "valid".

So my question is: How can I safely detect whether the parsed instance of `Foo` is valid and it is not an instance of another (similarly structured but completely different) Protobuf message type? Do I need to manually add the name of the message sent as a field (that would be stupid, but should work)?

Comment: Instead of defining the additional field with the name, you can use `Reflection` or `Descriptor`.

Comment: Protobuf encoding format is not self-describing. Basically, a binary encoding of any message can be successfully decoded into any other message; the latter may just end up with missing and/or unknown fields. The two parties must somehow agree on the type of the messages being exchanged, usually by documenting the communication protocol. Why again is one side sending `Bar` when the other side expects `Foo`?

Comment: @Ptaq666 I can **not** use these features, since I have to create the **expected** message of a concrete type on the receiving side. Therefore both reflection and descriptor **always** return the expected type.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I know that Protobuf is not self-describing, but I thought that there may be a functionality that can detect such a case, since we are talking about distinct types (not missing/unknown fields). The contract between sender and receiver **is** well-defined. We are not talking about a functionality here, this is about non-functional software quality, i.e. making the software robust against invalid/malformed input data. IMO this isn't such a special requirement. If there is no built-in feature I will go with the field approach and use `Descriptor::full_name()` on both sides.

Comment: @Florian no such feature exists, because it would be impossible to implement. Messages are fundamentally interchangeable as long as they don't have conflicting wire-type expectations (field 2 being a string in one, and a varint in the other, for example)

Comment: Well, malformed data can contain the correct `full_name` and then garbage in the rest of the fields. For all protobuf parser knows, the binary representation of `Bar` is merely a different (newer or older) revision of `Foo` - protobufs were specifically designed to be robust in the face of protocol evolution.

Comment: @FlorianWolters Whenever I've had to solve this problem in GPB I've always ended up putting alll the different messages I want to send in a oneof inside a wrapper message. Thus I'm alway only ever sending the wrapper, and it desribes what flavour of its oneoff it contains. I usually end up using ZMQ too, that takes care of message boundaries nicely. Serialisations like ASN.1 BER are self describing, allows one to "peek ahead" to see what's coming next. Very handy.

Comment: @bazza I do the same, as you can see in the OP. Though, this does not help if you want to protect yourself from wire compatible message of another type. I can't use one top-level messages for all messages, since I am dealing with multiple logical interfaces that do not share the same message bodies (also refer to OP).

Comment: @FlorianWolters, you could add a type string; I've seen this done (with a type int32 actually, but the principle is the same) but it is highly unsatisfactory because it has to be set / tested consistently everywhere; not very maintainable. If the generated classes have a handy function to return the object type as a string (I think the C++ classes do), you could use that to programatically set / test the type string. Failing all that, you'd have to have some other outer wrapper describing the contained GPB message's type.

Comment: @FlorianWolters, yes it looks like there's a method `name()` on the C++ objects. If you put that into a string field, then you could test for that at the other end without ever having to define string constants; it would all be sourced from the message names in the .proto file. So kind of a halfway solution, but at least easily maintained.